# What does _stscanf_s do?

Tags: c++, c, mfc

I saw this function in some code and I can't find documentation on google about it. Can someone explain what it does and are there any alternatives to this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsbaswba%28VS.80%29.aspx: it is a generic name for `sscanf_s`.

EDIT: which is conveniently documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6z7bya3%28VS.80%29.aspx). `_stscanf_s` is in TCHAR.H on Windows platforms. You can probably get away with using `sscanf_s` or `swscanf_s`.

Answer (score 2):

This MSDN article shows the `_stscanf_s` variant of their "secure" `sscanf` replacements:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6z7bya3(v=vs.80).aspx

It is a `TCHAR` variant, which means that it should be able to support ANSI characters, and Unicode/Multi-byte, depending on how the app is compiled.

You could (somewhat) replace it with `sscanf` on a more generic C/C++ implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the original question was about the difference between the `safe` and an older `unsafe` version of this function. I was looking for the same difference myself, and here's what it boils down to: [`_stscanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6z7bya3(VS.80).aspx) is different from `_stscanf` in the way it treats `%s` and `%c` specifiers. The `*_s` function will expect the sizes of their buffers to be passed in the next parameter, as the number of `TCHAR`s.

The best way to illustrate it is with these code samples:

```
    const TCHAR* pSrcBuff = L"Date: 2015-12-25";

    TCHAR buffDate[6] = {0};
    TCHAR chDash1 = 0, chDash2 = 0;
    int year = 0, month = 0, day = 0;

    //Old "unsafe" method -- DON'T USE IT!
    int count_found = _stscanf(pSrcBuff, 
        L"%s%d%c%d%c%d", 
        &buffDate,
        &year,
        &chDash1,
        &month,
        &chDash2,
        &day
        );

    if(count_found == 6)    //Number of specifiers read
    {
        //Success
        ASSERT(lstrcmp(buffDate, L"Date:") == 0);
        ASSERT(year == 2015);
        ASSERT(chDash1 == L'-');
        ASSERT(month == 12);
        ASSERT(chDash2 == L'-');
        ASSERT(day = 25);
    }
```

Note that if I change `buffDate[6]` to 5 or lower, it will result in a stack corruption, which can be exploited by "bad guys."

That is why Microsoft created a new "safer" method, that goes as such:

```
    const TCHAR* pSrcBuff = L"Date: 2015-12-25";

    TCHAR buffDate[6] = {0};
    TCHAR chDash1 = 0, chDash2 = 0;
    int year = 0, month = 0, day = 0;

    //"Safe" version of the method
    int count_found = _stscanf_s(pSrcBuff, 
        L"%s%d%c%d%c%d", 
        &buffDate, sizeof(buffDate) / sizeof(buffDate[0]),
        &year,
        &chDash1, sizeof(chDash1),
        &month,
        &chDash2, sizeof(chDash2),
        &day
        );

    if(count_found == 6)    //Number of specifiers read
    {
        //Success
        ASSERT(lstrcmp(buffDate, L"Date:") == 0);
        ASSERT(year == 2015);
        ASSERT(chDash1 == L'-');
        ASSERT(month == 12);
        ASSERT(chDash2 == L'-');
        ASSERT(day = 25);
    }
```

In this case, if you set `buffDate[6]` to 5 or lower, the `_stscanf_s` function will simply fail, without overwriting the end of the `buffDate` buffer.

Note that `scanf` group of functions is still dangerous (in my view) and will throw memory/page-fault exceptions if you mistake `%d` with `%s`, or if you don't match them with correct parameters.